# R - Changing values in a column and then changing column type

Tags: r

So, I have an imported set of NBA data that I got using `dataset <- read_csv(...)`. One of the columns named `Experience` contains both integers and characters, so its type is set to character. I need to change every `"R"` character to `0`'s, then set the column type of `Experience` to integer.

I'm just starting to use R, so I'm not quite sure what to do syntax-wise. Should I run a `for all 'R' in "Experience"` kind of loop? I'd know how to do it in Python, but I'm not sure how to do it in R. Thanks.

Comment: Could you share the result of running `dput(dataset)` on either the whole dataset of a sample? `dput` prints out your data frame into something others can copy-paste into their R console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you describe it, this should work:

```
dataset[ dataset$Experience == "R", "Experience" ] <- 0
```

does the replacement job in `R`'s vectorised manner:

`dataset[ dataset$Experience == "R", ]` (the last comma matters) selects all rows in the data frame where the value of the column `Experience` is equal to `"R"`.

`dataset[ , "Experience" ]` (again, the comma matters) selects the values in column `"Experience"`.

Combined into one, exactly the values you are targeting are selected, and then the value `0` is assigned where the `"R"` was.

You can find out more with the built-in help: `?"[.data.frame"`.

And then,

```
dataset$Experience <- as.integer( dataset$Experience )
```

takes care of the conversion.

Sample:

```
dataset <- structure(list(bla = 1:10, Experience = c("50", "49", "R", "47", "46", "R", "44", "R", "42", "41")), .Names = c("bla", "Experience"), row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = "data.frame")
dataset
   bla Experience
1    1         50
2    2         49
3    3          R
4    4         47
5    5         46
6    6          R
7    7         44
8    8          R
9    9         42
10  10         41
dataset[ dataset$Experience == "R", "Experience" ] <- 0
dataset$Experience <- as.integer( dataset$Experience )
str( dataset )
'data.frame':   10 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ bla       : int  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
 $ Experience: int  50 49 0 47 46 0 44 0 42 41
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply! What exactly is `dataset[ dataset$Experience == "R", "Experience" ] <- 0` equivalent to in something like python? What are we "doing" in `dataset[ dataset$Experience == "R", "Experience" ] <- 0`? Thanks.

Comment: I don't know Python but anyway, will add some comments in my original answer.